# Determine which element comes first in the HTML/DOM?

Tags: jquery

I need to determine which element comes first in my markup, such as an `input` or `select`. For example

```
<body>
    <input type="text" />
    <select><option>Test</option></select>
<body>
```

In this case, the `input` comes first in the DOM whereas

```
<body>
    <select><option>Test</option></select>
    <input type="text" />
<body>
```

in this case, `select` comes first. Any way to do this using jQuery? Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't want the very first element, I ONLY want to know if between the input and select element, which comes first. There could be other elements before the `select` and `input` elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
if `$('select:first').index() < $('input:first').index()` then the `select` is first

See a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLmMB/

Comment: This would work as long as the first `select` and `input` are siblings. If not, `.index()` wouldn't be a reliable indicator.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the *very* first element in the `<body>`, you can use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) like this:

```
$("body > :first-child")
```

For example your in first example:

```
alert($("body > :first-child")[0].nodeName);​ //alerts "INPUT"
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZMHMK/)

---

Or to get the first input type, you can do this:

```
$(":input:first")
```

for example:

```
alert($(":input:first")[0].nodeName);​ //alerts "INPUT"
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZMHMK/1/)

Comment: I don't want the very first element, I want to know if between the input and select element, which comes first

Comment: @Axsuul - Updated to only look at input type elements :)

Comment: @Gert - That would find *any* first child at any level, so it'd select lots of elements :)

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to the situation, but if there happens to be a `textarea` earlier on the page, `:input` would select that.

Comment: @patrick - True, I think we're missing a lot of information though, e.g. how to identify these elements, do they not have names or anything? It seems unlikely the parameters given in the question are the *only* requirements here.

Comment: Nick - Agreed. Not much to go on here. Just noting that there's a possible (though perhaps remote) chance of failure with `:input`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know which comes first in the entire document, you could do this:

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/85zUZ/ *Change the order then click Run at the top.*

```
var theFirst = $('input,select').first()[0].tagName;

alert( theFirst );
```

jQuery returns elements in the order they appear in the DOM, so `.first()` will grab the first one in order of appearance.